# SSE Emitter : Manage timeouts and complete()

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events, eventemitter

I am writing a web app where multiple listeners(Evcentsource SSE clients JS) will be connected to my server . what i want to do is

1. Store SSE emitter per connected listener : can be done in memory or any other means by assigning id to each client I am able to achieve this so far
2. Now the question ; How do i send a response/event to specific client connected to my web app ? while doing this SSEEmmiters stored are either getting completed or timed out. how do i prevent this ? how do i keep sseEmmiter available open for infinite time (till client closes) and send events selectively .

Comment: Which server-side language (and any libraries) are you using? Can you add it as a tag?

Comment: To keep an SSE connection open indefinitely (or until the client closes it), you can indeed send a "heartbeat" message at fixed intervals. This approach helps to prevent the connection from timing out due to inactivity.

Also at client side at a retry logic if there is a timeout then client can retry instead  of server keep sending events

Answer (score 10):

If you want the sseEmmiter available open for infinite time, you can simply set the time out to -1L

and to send events selectively put all of sseEmmiters in a map with specific key to use it when you want to send event 
 like i did in this code .

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "api/person")
public class PersonController {

 @Autowired
 private PersonRepository personRepository;
 private Map<String, SseEmitter> onPersonAddedSseEmitters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 @PostMapping(path = "/add")
 public @ResponseBody
 String addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
   person.setId(new Random().nextLong());
   personRepository.save(person);
   onPersonAddedSseEmitters.forEach((key, sseEmitter) -> {
     try {
       if (person.getName().startsWith(key.split("-")[0])) {
         sseEmitter.send(person);
       }
     } catch (Exception ignored) {
       sseEmitter.complete();
       onPersonAddedSseEmitters.remove(key);
     }
   });
   return "Saved";
 }

 @GetMapping(path = "/onPersonAdded/{prefix}")
 public SseEmitter onPersonAdded(@PathVariable String prefix) {
   SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
   onPersonAddedSseEmitters.put(prefix + "-" + new Random().nextLong(), sseEmitter);
   return sseEmitter;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the timeout on the SseEmitter. The default timeout is rather short.

The [SseEmitter timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/SseEmitter.html#SseEmitter-java.lang.Long-) is in milliseconds. It is a session timeout, not affected by activity on the session.

The timeout needs to be set to the expected duration of the session, in milliseconds. So, 86400000 (or more) is entirely appropriate.

Comment: I don't know how it works with reactive approach, but in case of standard thread-per-request scenario this will lead to memory leaks.  The container tracks the connection using DeferredResult even if the client terminated the connection. There's an open bug for it in ServletAPI Spec [#44](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/servlet-api/issues/44)

Answer (score 4):

Details about how you should set a proper timeout. 2 ways of doing this with Spring

1. Using the [SseEmitter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/SseEmitter.html#SseEmitter-java.lang.Long-) constructor

```java
SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(15000L); // Example for 15s
```

2. Using Spring property

```java
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout: 15000
```

Quote from documentation

> By default not set in which case the default configured in the MVC
>   Java Config or the MVC namespace is used, or if that's not set, then
>   the timeout depends on the default of the underlying server.

Comment: I know this has been a long time but is there a way I could know when the SseEmitter time outed. When the sseEmitter times out, I get message in "eventSource.onerror" event listener. Is there any way I could differenciate between other errors and timeouts ?

Comment: @AmitPokhrel On the server side, you can use **SseEmitter.onTimeout()** and **SseEmitter.onError()** to detect and react to those events. 
E.g. `emitter.onTimeout(() -> { System.out.println("Timeout detected") }`

Answer (score 2):

To solve the timeout issue, we used `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the timeout and it worked perfectly fine.