# How to get mysql insert percentage from web page?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot project. In the project, there are multiple databases; just one of them belongs to me. So I wanted to get the data from outsources and insert them all into my database. I usually have a scheduled thread that fulfills the mission, yet I want to make available to do it manually over a web page. I used Server Sent Events to get insertion status as a percentage with a process bar(asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561331/what-is-the-reason-of-responsebodyemitter-is-already-set-complete-exception-in)), but I have faced lots of problems I couldn't cope with.

The question is: Which way can I use to get the insertion status from the server to show my client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally dismissed to use SSE and used websocket like as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089258/11640370) stated.