# How to select EventSource timeout value

Tags: server-sent-events

In most libraries there is `timeout` parameter for `SSE` connection which is usually set to 1 second or to infinity by default.

This means, that server will close SSE connection in 1 second, and client after that should reconnect again.

What i should take into account selecting the value for SSE connection timeout ?

Why not set it to 10 minutes or 24 hours for example ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the parameter you mean?  Are you referring to the `retry` header, set by the client? Or is this a server-side setting? In which case I think the question needs a tag for the server-side language and/or library being used.

Comment: I am reffering to a Spring SseEmitter timeout parameter https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/SseEmitter.html

You right, this is server-side setting, which is basically means the living time of your connection. I can't find anywere what this value should be.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40462780/841830 ?